# How to get path of directory in gunzip bundle

Tags: tar, gunzip

My gunzip structure is like something like this

```
archive.tgz/manager-34038240834402384/temp1
                                     /temp2/temp4/temp5
                                     /temp3/temp6
```

I just need the string `'manager-34038240834402384'` without extracting whole bundle. How to get it?
I tried tar -tvf which gives me whole path, but I just want above string. How to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tar --list -f archive.tgz | head -n 1
```